Store output from multiple batch commands in variables
I am trying to make a batch file run a couple of different commands, then display all the results together at the end.
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET Counter=1
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth`) DO (
  SET "VariableA!Counter!=%%F"
  SET /a Counter=!Counter!+1)

SET Counter=1
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth`) DO (
  SET "VariableB!Counter!=%%F"
  SET /a Counter=!Counter!+1)

SET Counter=1
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`) DO (
  SET "VariableC!Counter!=%%F"
  SET /a Counter=!Counter!+1)

SET Counter=1
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`SFC /scannow`) DO (
  SET "VariableD!Counter!=%%F"
  SET /a Counter=!Counter!+1)

@ECHO %VariableA4%
@ECHO %VariableA5%
@ECHO %VariableB4%
@ECHO %VariableB5%
@ECHO %VariableC4%
@ECHO %VariableC5%
@ECHO %VariableD3%
@ECHO %VariableD4%

ENDLOCAL
pause

I tried the code posted above, but only got a result on the first two variables
@ECHO %VariableA4% & @ECHO %VariableA5%
All the next variables did not display anything/ get assigned any value from 2'nd, 3'rd and 4'th command.
The normal output of each command:
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth
C:\WINDOWS\system32>DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.19041.3636

Image Version: 10.0.19045.4529

No component store corruption detected.
The operation completed successfully.

DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth
C:\WINDOWS\system32>DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.19041.3636

Image Version: 10.0.19045.4529

[==========================100.0%==========================] No component store corruption detected.
The operation completed successfully.

DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
C:\WINDOWS\system32>DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.19041.3636

Image Version: 10.0.19045.4529

[==========================100.0%==========================] The restore operation completed successfully.
The operation completed successfully.

SFC /scannow
C:\WINDOWS\system32>SFC /scannow

Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.

My goal is to make the CMD window display something like this at the very end:
    CheckHealth:
    No component store corruption detected.
    The operation completed successfully.
    (only line 4 and 5 of the normal command output)

    ScanHealth
    No component store corruption detected.
    The operation completed successfully.
    (only line 4 and 5 of the normal command output)

    RestoreHealth
    The restore operation completed successfully.
    The operation completed successfully.
    (only line 4 and 5 of the normal command output)

    SFC /scannow
    Verification 100% complete.
    Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.
    (only line 3 and 4 of the normal command output)

I appreciate the help anyone could give.

What does the output from each of DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth, DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth, DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth, and SFC /scannow look like for you, and we may be able to assist. (I wouldn't be willing to run those on my machine, if I had one). Please [Edit] your question to provide the unmodified output from each of those commands, within a code box. Thank you.

TBH, even if I could understand why you would want to delay the output from each command until they had all completed, I'd have thought that it would be simpler to send the output from each command to a file, then just type the file at the end, and optionally delete it afterwards. Your currently submitted code seems to rely upon you already knowing exactly how many lines with content will always be returned, and I find that difficult to believe.

Are you expecting to see the individual stages of each progress indicator bar, for those DISM commands, as well as their repeated header information? And each of the increasing percentage numbers for the SFC progress too?

The @ in each @ECHO %Variab… is redundant. ECHOing is turned off once an ECHO  OFF command is executed. The @ means "Turn echo off for this command". Try using a SET Variable command, which will display the values of all variables whose names begin Variable. This may indicate why the display you are currently seeing is not as expected.

1/2
I do not mind if the output of each command is displayed when they normally should, but I want to additionally see them at the very end after all commands have run. Just a short and simple overview if everything went as it should.
It is preferable if the output/answer of each command is temporarily stored in a variable/ram only to be displayed once, then discarded.
I do not know how many lines of code will be returned, but I assume it will always be the same? Something like "the operation was successfull" or "the operation was not successful".

2/2
I do not need any induvidual stages or progress bar atc, only the end result of all operations displayed at the very end.
I tried to only use ECHO variable (without the @ at the beginning of each ECHO), but I got the results displayed twice. Unsure if I have done something wrong...

You need the last two lines and you know how many lines there will be (I trust your words here). So you can skip the first n (unneeded) lines. You just have to filter out the progress lines, because you don't know (or don't want to count) how many there are.
I took the freedom to adapt your counter method a bit.
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set counter=0
FOR /F "skip=5 tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`dism /online /cleanup-image /checkhealth`) DO (
  SET /a Counter+=1
  SET "Variable!Counter!=%%F"
)
FOR /F "skip=5 tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth^|find /v "["`) DO (
  SET /a Counter+=1
  SET "Variable!Counter!=%%F"
)
  set variable
  set counter
echo ====== Summary ======
echo checkhealth:
echo %variable1%
echo %variable2%
echo scanhealth:
echo %variable3%
echo %variable4%
echo etc.

Note: this will fail miserably if the number of lines differ (in case of an error or other unexpected output, or not running with admin privilege (less lines, nothing to process))

Thank you very much, just what I needed.
Have a nice day!

@Batman, if this is the best answer, please select the check mark on the left at the beginning of the answer. This lets others know the solution that worked for you. This is how SO works.

Done, thanks for the tip.
